# F# Type Provider error, attempt to read when Reader is closed

Tags: mysql, f#, type-providers

I'm trying to follow the instructions for SQLProvider MySQL Provider, on Linux Mint, in either MonoDevelop or VS Code. I have:

```
let [<Literal>] connString = @"Server=localhost;Database=PriceData;User=root;Password=-----;SslMode=none"              
let [<Literal>] connexStringName = "DefaultConnectionString"            
let [<Literal>] dbVendor    = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MYSQL
let [<Literal>] resPath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"/../../../Simulations 2018-07-29/packages/MySqlConnector.0.43.0/lib/net45"
let [<Literal>] indivAmount = 1000
let [<Literal>] useOptTypes = true
```

and

```
type SQL = SqlDataProvider< dbVendor,
                            connString,
                            ResolutionPath = resPath,
                            IndividualsAmount = indivAmount,
                            UseOptionTypes = useOptTypes
                            Owner = "HR" >  ///"PriceData">
```

This type declaration errors out with:

```
The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: 
Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.
```

This one completely baffles me. I've never had an error like it in earlier times with Windows and Visual Studio. And I can't find anything searching that seems relevant to F# and type providers.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Do you know your Mono, MySQL, F# Core and F# Data versions by any chance?

Comment: Hi WE, it looks like Mono is 5.10.1.47, MySQL is 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, F# Core appears to be 4.5.2, and FSharp Data 2.4.6. Thanks for the comment.